# PHP: Attempting to connect to a memcache server, but getting "Permission Error (13)"

Tags: php, memcached

When I try to connect to my memcache server, I get "... Permission Error (13) ..." in my PHP error log. I can connect through telnet and even get a response, but can't connect through PHP.

The script works when run from the command line, but when run through Apache it fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is most like a problem with SELinux or your firewall.

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/redhat-fedora-linux-help/46840-fsockopen-error-13-permission-denied.html